# Troubleshooting Rapidminer Server on Windows 10

Tags: localhost, rapidminer

I have just installed Rapidminer Server on my Windows 10 machine and I am not able to reach the web interface.

The service seems to run just fine.

```
The RapidMiner_Server service is starting.
The RapidMiner_Server service was started successfully.
```

And I also left the default hostname and port, `localhost:8080`.

Could it be that instead of the Oracle JDK8 I got the Open JDK8 and instead of MySQL I got MariaDB?
Following is my configuration file.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.7">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>

 <system-properties>
      <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
     <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
        <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="2048"/>
 </system-properties>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="migration" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="migration.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="authentication-audit" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="authentication-audit.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="org.springframework.security.saml.log">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="authentication-audit"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
               <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
               <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="de.rapidanalytics.ejb.migration">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="migration"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/RapidAnalyticsDS"
 pool-name="RapidAnalyticsDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="false"
 use-ccm="true">
 <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rapidminer_server</connection-url>
 <connection-property name="rewriteBatchedStatements">true</connection-property>
 <driver>mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar</driver>
 <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
 <pool>
  <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
  <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
  <prefill>true</prefill>
  <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
  <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
 </pool>
 <security>
  <user-name>root</user-name>
  <password>toor</password>
 </security>
 <validation>
     <!-- Ensure that a DB outage is detected and Server is able to restore DB connections afterwards again -->
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>5000</background-validation-millis>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
  <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
 </validation>
 <statement>
  <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
  <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
 </statement>
</datasource>
<drivers>
 <driver name="mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar" module="com/mysql">
  <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
  <driver-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
 </driver>
</drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
            <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.5">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.5">
            <cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="local-web" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="local-web" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.2">
   <mail-session jndi-name="java:/Mail" debug="false" from="user@localhost.com">
                <custom-server name="smtp" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp">
                    <login name="username" password="password"/>
                    
                </custom-server>
                <!-- pop3-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-pop3"/ -->
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.2">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="RapidAnalyticsEJBDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
    <security-domain name="radoop-kerberos" cache-type="default">
     <authentication>
            <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
                <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
            </login-module>
         </authentication>
    </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="hadoop_default" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.apache.hadoop.security.login.GenericOSLoginModule" flag="required">
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="com.mapr.security.maprsasl.MaprSecurityLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="checkUGI" value="false"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="org.apache.hadoop.security.login.HadoopLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="principalPriority" value="com.mapr.security.MapRPrincipal"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="Client_simple" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.mapr.security.simplesasl.GenericLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="authMech" value="SIMPLE-SECURITY"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="Client" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.mapr.security.maprsasl.MaprSecurityLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="checkUGI" value="false"/>
                            <module-option name="authMech" value="MAPR-SECURITY"/>
                            <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="ra-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
   <!--
            <connector name="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="false" secure="true">
                <ssl name="ssl" password="secret" protocol="TLSv1" key-alias="rms" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/rms.keystore" />
            </connector>
             -->
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
   <virtual-server name="ra-host" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="ROOT">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:localhost}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:localhost}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:localhost}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="any">
   <any-ipv4-address/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="any" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
   <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
  <!-- outbound-socket-binding name="mail-pop3">
            <remote-destination host="pop.localhost" port="110"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding -->
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the config file looks good so far, but unfortunately it doesn't help much.

Can you check these two logs for any errors:

```
 ./rapidminer-server-home/bin/server.log (best clean it and then try to start the server again)
```

and

```
./rapidminer-server-home/bin/server-installer-$DATE_OF_INSTALL.log
```

But I think the actual issue is the MariaDB, as it is not officially supported by RapidMiner server, see [here](https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/server/install/system-requirements.html).

I recommend you to re-post your question in the [RapidMiner community](https://community.rapidminer.com/), where you will find help from very experienced RapidMiner users.

Comment: That is correct, RapidMiner doen't support MariaBD. https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/studio/installation/system-requirements.html